# Prevent Jackson from setting links field null when the client sends "_links" : null (links inherited from spring-hateoas RepresentationModel class)

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind, spring-hateoas

I have Spring Boot API that uses spring-hateoas.

I have a domain class that is used for request and response in my controller. The domain class inherits from spring-hateoas class RepresentationModel, therefore it contains a "links" field.

For some reason (that I cannot control) a client is sending `"_links": null` in the request which is forcing links field to be null, after it had been properly initialized with an empty List. See [RepresentationModel.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/blob/1.2.x/src/main/java/org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.java#L43)

Null links field in the request is causing issues in my application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Links must not be null!
  at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:201) ~[spring-core-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
  at org.springframework.hateoas.Links.<init>(Links.java:54) ~[spring-hateoas-1.2.6.jar:1.2.6]
  at org.springframework.hateoas.Links.of(Links.java.79) ~[spring-hateoas-1.2.6.jar:1.2.6]
  at org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel.getLinks(RepresentationModel.java:210) ~[spring-hateoas-1.2.6.jar:1.2.6]
  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccesor158.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccesorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccesorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_292]
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:689) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
  at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAsField(SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.java:208) ~[jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:2.11.4]
```

One thing I tried was configuring Jackson to ignore links field on marshalling (@JsonIgonoreProperties) but this is also affecting my response by removing HATEOAS links from it (this Jackson configuration is application wide)

Looking at RepresentationModel class from spring-hateoas, seems like links field is designed not to be handled directly. It is updated only through the corresponding methods in RepresentationModel after it was initialized.

I was able to *reinitialize* links field through reflection.

```
  try {
    Field field = obj.getClass().getSuperClass().getDeclaredField("links");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(obj, new ArrayList<>());
    field.setAccessible(false);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(e);
  }
```

Is there a better way to reinitialize HATEOAS links field in a RepresenationModel object which already has null links?

Is there a better approach to prevent the client request from affecting the incoming object this way?